# ThreeJS Editor Transparent Background

Tags: three.js

I'm using the https://threejs.org/editor/ to export a webgl animation and I'm trying to figure out how to convert it to have a transparent background.

I'm essentially trying to put a div with text behind my animating threejs render.

I tried adding

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true,} );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0 );
```

but it doesn't seem to be working

I'm new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Attached is my code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="Three.js Editor">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 13px;
                background-color: black;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .text {
                font-size: 30vw;
                color: white;
                font-family: helvetica;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 0; 
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body ontouchstart="">


        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>


        <script>

            var loader = new THREE.FileLoader();
            loader.load( 'app.json', function ( text ) {

                var player = new APP.Player();
                player.load( JSON.parse( text ) );
                player.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                player.play();

                document.body.appendChild( player.dom );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', function () {
                    player.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                } );

            } );

        </script>

        <div class="text">Text Here</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

And .js file

```
var APP = {

    Player: function () {

        var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var events = {};

        var dom = document.createElement( 'div' );

        this.dom = dom;

        this.width = 500;
        this.height = 500;

        this.load = function ( json ) {

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true,} );
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0 );
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

            var project = json.project;

            if ( project.shadows ) renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            if ( project.vr ) renderer.vr.enabled = true;

            dom.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            this.setScene( loader.parse( json.scene ) );
            this.setCamera( loader.parse( json.camera ) );

            events = {
                init: [],
                start: [],
                stop: [],
                keydown: [],
                keyup: [],
                mousedown: [],
                mouseup: [],
                mousemove: [],
                touchstart: [],
                touchend: [],
                touchmove: [],
                update: []
            };

            var scriptWrapParams = 'player,renderer,scene,camera';
            var scriptWrapResultObj = {};

            for ( var eventKey in events ) {

                scriptWrapParams += ',' + eventKey;
                scriptWrapResultObj[ eventKey ] = eventKey;

            }

            var scriptWrapResult = JSON.stringify( scriptWrapResultObj ).replace( /\"/g, '' );

            for ( var uuid in json.scripts ) {

                var object = scene.getObjectByProperty( 'uuid', uuid, true );

                if ( object === undefined ) {

                    console.warn( 'APP.Player: Script without object.', uuid );
                    continue;

                }

                var scripts = json.scripts[ uuid ];

                for ( var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i ++ ) {

                    var script = scripts[ i ];

                    var functions = ( new Function( scriptWrapParams, script.source + '\nreturn ' + scriptWrapResult + ';' ).bind( object ) )( this, renderer, scene, camera );

                    for ( var name in functions ) {

                        if ( functions[ name ] === undefined ) continue;

                        if ( events[ name ] === undefined ) {

                            console.warn( 'APP.Player: Event type not supported (', name, ')' );
                            continue;

                        }

                        events[ name ].push( functions[ name ].bind( object ) );

                    }

                }

            }

            dispatch( events.init, arguments );

        };

        this.setCamera = function ( value ) {

            camera = value;
            camera.aspect = this.width / this.height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            if ( renderer.vr.enabled ) {

                dom.appendChild( THREE.WEBVR.createButton( renderer ) );

            }

        };

        this.setScene = function ( value ) {

            scene = value;

        };

        this.setSize = function ( width, height ) {

            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;

            if ( camera ) {

                camera.aspect = this.width / this.height;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            }

            if ( renderer ) {

                renderer.setSize( width, height );

            }

        };

        function dispatch( array, event ) {

            for ( var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                array[ i ]( event );

            }

        }

        var time, prevTime;

        function animate() {

            time = performance.now();

            try {

                dispatch( events.update, { time: time, delta: time - prevTime } );

            } catch ( e ) {

                console.error( ( e.message || e ), ( e.stack || "" ) );

            }

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

            prevTime = time;

        }

        this.play = function () {

            prevTime = performance.now();

            document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown );
            document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchend', onDocumentTouchEnd );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove );

            dispatch( events.start, arguments );

            renderer.setAnimationLoop( animate );

        };

        this.stop = function () {

            document.removeEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown );
            document.removeEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove );
            document.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart );
            document.removeEventListener( 'touchend', onDocumentTouchEnd );
            document.removeEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove );

            dispatch( events.stop, arguments );

            renderer.setAnimationLoop( null );

        };

        this.dispose = function () {

            while ( dom.children.length ) {

                dom.removeChild( dom.firstChild );

            }

            renderer.dispose();

            camera = undefined;
            scene = undefined;
            renderer = undefined;

        };

        //

        function onDocumentKeyDown( event ) {

            dispatch( events.keydown, event );

        }

        function onDocumentKeyUp( event ) {

            dispatch( events.keyup, event );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            dispatch( events.mousedown, event );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            dispatch( events.mouseup, event );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            dispatch( events.mousemove, event );

        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            dispatch( events.touchstart, event );

        }

        function onDocumentTouchEnd( event ) {

            dispatch( events.touchend, event );

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

            dispatch( events.touchmove, event );

        }

    }

};
```

Comment: https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-tips.html#transparent-canvas

Answer (score 0):

You might need to adjust the CSS `z-index` of the `<canvas>` that ThreeJS is creating.

Note that the WebGLRenderer constructor has an overload that lets you pass in a canvas, instead of letting ThreeJS create it. This might be a useful in your case, so that you can easily control where the element lives in your DOM.